# Is there any way to use vue3 packages in Nuxt2?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I am currently building a blog and have been using [Quill](https://github.com/quilljs/quill) as my default TextEditor.But as I change from **vue3 to nuxt** for **SSR**, I received an error concerning with the versions of quill and nuxt.Is there anyway that I can still use vue3 packages in Nuxt?

Comment: Providing us with the actual error + more context will solve the issue faster and be seen better by the people who may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the package for Vue2 so far: https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-quill-editor

As to answer the general answer of

> is X compatible with Vue2?

You need to check per-package. Some are (Vue2 + 3), some aren't (Vue3 or Vue2 only).